# Mapping a nested NSDictionary to a custom model

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, model, nsdictionary

I read data from an xml file, and the simplified `NSDictionary` is looking like this:

```
{
    Name = "Song Title";
    Album = "Album Title";
    "Album Artist" = "Album Artist Title";
    Artist = "Artist Title";
}, ...
```

I want to make models `ITSong`, `ITArtist`, `ITAlbum`, and so on.
The structure should be smart, so I could expand it with `ITComposer`, or whatever.

The problem is that the models are nested.
The `ITArtist` should hold an array of `ITAlbum`s, and an `ITAlbum` should hold an array of `ITSong`s.

This would require a bunch of nested for-loops, checking for unique `NSString`s for the specific keys, and would have to be repeated for the album, the artist, the album artist, and so on. Which doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I want to check if there is a library that can do this.

How can I map a complex `NSDictionary` to custom models the right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestKit (http://restkit.org, you'll need https://github.com/RestKit/RKXMLReaderSerialization as well) does a good job of deserializing XML and JSON into Objective-C classes.  You define the relationship between the XML and the classes and it will automatically create the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent model object should take care of initialize the child objects.

lets say for ITArtist

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)artistDictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.artistName = [artistDictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSMutableArray *albumObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSArray *albumDicts = [artistDictionary valueForKey:@"albums"];
        for each albumDict {
               ITAlbum *albumModelObject = [[ITAlbum alloc] initWithDictionary:albumDict];//This should take care of initializing the songs
              [albumObjects addObject:albumModelObject];
               [albumModelObject release];
        }
       self.albums =  albumObjects;
       [albumObjects release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet there's a framework around that does it, but then again Key-Value-Coding should provide everything you need out of the box. I'd create a base class, say ITObject with an initializer that uses `setAttributesFromDictionary:`

```
- (id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setAttributesFromDictionary:dict];
    }
    return self;
}
```

That will take care of all your normal properties. In case of nested dicts and arrays you just implement (for example in ITArtist : ITObject) something like

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"albums"]) {
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSMutableArray *myMembers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[value count]];
            for (id valueMember in value) {
                ITAlbum *album = [[[ITAlbum alloc] initWithDict:valueMember] autorelease];
                [myMembers addObject:album];
            }
            self.albums = myMembers;
        }
    } else {
        [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you think of Having an XML File as per your custom dataset and then have a NSDictionary , look at the one example here... [Simple XML to NSDictionary Converter](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)